# How to check if element is present or not using Playwright and timeout parameter

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I need to find a specific element in my webpage. The element may be in the page or not.

This code is giving me error if the element is not visible:

```
error_text = self.page.wait_for_selector(
            self.ERROR_MESSAGE, timeout=7000).inner_text()
```

How can I look for the element using timeout, and get a bool telling me if the element is found or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `page.is_visible(selector, **kwargs)` for this as this returns a boolean value. [Playwright Docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-is-visible),

```py
bool = page.is_visible(selector, timeout=7000)
print(bool)

#OR

if page.is_visible(selector, timeout=7000):
    print("Element Found")
else:
    print("Element not Found")
```

You can also use `expect` assertion if you directly want to assert the presence of the element and fail the tests if the condition is not met.

```py
expect(page.locator("selector")).to_have_count(1, timeout=7000)
```

Comment: The docs indicate that the timeout kwarg is ignored. My application of this method is crashing unless I put a page wait in there.

Comment: I was able to make this work using [wait_for_selector()](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector) 'if page.wait_for_selector("text=Sign in", timeout=7000) is not None:'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `page.wait_for_selector(selector, timeout)` with try except block to check the web element is present or not if that element takes some time to load.

```
try:
    page.wait_for_selector(selector, timeout)
    print('element found')
except:
    print('element not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like it, wish there was something convenient, but I am using like this - showing Javascript code

```
async function isPresent(locator: Locator): Promise<boolean> {
 let isPresent = false;
 try {
   await locator.waitFor({ state: 'attached', timeout: 20 });
   isPresent = true;
 } catch(err) {}
 return isPresent;
}
```